# Internet connection sharing without Network Manager

Tags: internet, iptables, interface, dnsmasq, ip-forward

I followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29) for setting up a shared internet connection with iptables. Specifically, I:

1. Added a network interface for my second NIC in /etc/network/interfaces like so:

   `auto eth1`

   `iface eth1 inet static`

   `address 192.168.1.100`

   `netmask 255.255.255.0`
2. Entered these rules exactly:

   `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`

   `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

   `sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING`

   `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
3. Saved my rules to a file and added it to /etc/rc.local
4. Enabled IP forwarding by changing the value of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward to 1
5. Uncommented the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in /etc/sysctl.conf
6. Restarted

Now, when I plug my laptop into the eth1 interface, I get an IP address and can ping the gateway, but I can't reach anything outside of that. i.e., I can't ping 8.8.8.8.

In case it's relevant, my other interface is a PPPoE connection. It looks like this:

```
auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 up
provider dsl-provider

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

I thought maybe the problem was that dnsmasq wasn't assigning nameservers, so I added `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4` under both interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces. That didn't help, so I tried adding the nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf. No help there. Finally, I tried adding them to /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

This didn't help either. I'm not sure however if my problem really has anything to do with nameservers or if this is just another case of outdated, worthless documentation.

I was able to get this working with Network Manager at one point, but I didn't like how Network Manager didn't let me assign a DHCP range. So I'd like to avoid going back to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -i eth1 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Thanks again to g0rdon at #openwrt :)